# Find the general solution of $ y'''- y'' - 9y' +9y = 0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of  $ y'''- y'' - 9y' +9y = 0 $

The answer is

$y=c_{1}e^{-3x}+c_{2}e^{3x}+c_{3}e^{x}$

how do i approach this problem?

Comment: how do you do usually?

Comment: Open a book on linear differential equations.

Comment: @Johny: I think you wrote the answer wrong. Hint: how do you write the characteristic equation and what do the root mean?

Comment: Do you know the approach that uses the polynomial $r^3-r^2-9r+9=0$ and finds its roots?

If the roots are distinct then $y=c_1e^{r_1 x}+c_2 e^{r_2 x}+c_3 e^{r_3 x}$ will be your solution.

Answer (score 5):

There is a "universal" approach to this type of problem. We look for solutions of the form $e^{mx}$. Substituting $y=e^{mx}$ into our DE, we get after a short while $m^3e^{mx}-m^2e^{mx}-9me^{mx}+9e^{mx}=0$.

This will be satisfied if and only if $m^3-m^2-9m+9=0$.

The above cubic equation happens to be easy to solve. It can be rewritten as $m^2(m-1)-9(m-1)=0$, and then as $(m-1)(m^2-9)=0$. The solutions are $m=1$, $m=3$, and $m=-3$.

So $e^x$, $e^{3x}$, and $e^{-3x}$ are solutions of our DE. Because our DE is *linear* and right-hand side is $0$, that means that for any constants $A$, $B$, and $C$, $y=Ae^x+Be^{3x}+Ce^{-3x}$ is a solution.

Because our differential equation has order $3$, and (it turns out) the $3$ solutions we found are *linearly independent*, all solutions are of the form $y=Ae^x+Be^{3x}+Ce^{-3x}$.

**Remark:** The above is a more or less **universal** method for dealing with linear differential equations that have constant coefficients and right-hand side $0$. There are some complications. If the polynomial equation that we get has multiple roots (example: $(m-1)(m-3)^2$) then some adjustment needs to be made. It turns out that in that example, $e^x$, $e^{3x}$, and $xe^{3x}$ will give us a set of basic solutions.

Also, if some of the roots of the polynomial we get are non-real, we proably want to make an adjustment, and express a solution like $y=e^{5ix}$, which is technically correct, in terms of sines and cosines.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: use characteristic equation $$y'''- y'' - 9y' +9y = 0 $$ $$(D^3-D^2-9D+9)y=0$$ then $$(D-1)(D-3)(D+3)y=0$$we have $D=1,3,-3$ and $$y=c_{1}e^{-3x}+c_{2}e^{3x}+c_{3}e^{x}$$

Comment: @Johny your welcome

Answer (score 0):

Try to substitute $e^{\lambda x}$ in the equation and solve the algebraic equation in $\lambda$ as is usually done for second order homogeneous ODEs.

Comment: Unless there is a very good reason, we prefer not to arbitrarily delete good content: the answers could well help other users in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following differential equation:
$$ y^{'''}-y^{''}-9y^{'}+9y=0 $$

Applying the Laplace transform:
$$ Y(s)(s^{3}-s^{2}-9s+9)=K_{1}+sK_{2}+s^{2}K_{3} $$

Rearranging:

$$ Y(s)=\frac{K_{1}+sK_{2}+s^{2}K_{3}}{(s+3)(s-3)(s-1)} $$

I can decompose the division into simple fractions:

$$ Y(s)=\frac{C_{1}}{s+3}+\frac{C_{2}}{s-3}+\frac{C_{1}}{s-1}$$

Doing the inverse laplace transform:

$y=C_{1}e^{-3x}+C_{2}e^{3x}+C_{3}e^{x}$